# python pandas plot series matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a line graph using the following python pandas information: index which is the date/period, 'student' which is the number of students who have visited per period and region which is where the students are visiting from.  Ideally, I would like the number of students on the y axis, the date on the x axis and the region to be a different color or at least a different line associated with each region:

```
Year    Region    Student
2013    North     1
2013    South     2
2013    East      5
2014    North     3
2014    South     7
2014    East      10
```

I am having trouble finding examples of being able to utilize a dataframe series (i.e., vs having to list each element explicitly and instead reference the index as the x axis or student as the y axis) by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through your groups after you use `groupby` to group your data by `Region`, then plot each one. Here is a basic scaffold of code that you can build on:

```
for region, data in df.groupby('Region'):
    plt.plot(data['Year'], data['Student'], label=region)

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number of Students')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hi sacul, while this is probably a bad example, is there a way to turn this chart into a pie graph based on region and sum( students) from that region?

Comment: That's a whole different problem. I'd suggest asking a new question with specifics as to how you want the pie graph to look. But you can take a look at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html, it might be enough for you to adapt the code above